# shortcut key to launch an app

Tags: android, android-shortcut

Is it possible to define a shortcut key to launch the app I'm developing for android?

Can a service running in the background get hardware button events like the camera or send button for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put your Application on your Home screen?

With that, it'll be just one click away, like you want.

Comment: I want to be able to access it from other application as well.
For example, if you have a music player that run in the background, I want to be able to skip a song or change the volume while navigating a map.

Comment: can you explain about the long-click home-button?
I'm not familiar with it

Comment: When you long press the Home button, you see list with the currently running Activities. You can easily switch between Activities, by choosing the one you are interested in from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar situation. But i got the solution by doing this.
U can go to settings-> Applications -> Quick Launch select the key and application u wanna launch and the press and hold F5 and the key u have selected. ur application ll launch!